# How to convert Excel to csv to Json (Without having text numbers convert to numbers)?

Tags: json, excel, csv

I'm trying to convert an excel file to a json file, while not losing any data.

I have a column in the excel that contains values which are both text and numbers (but both are stored as text).

First, I've set the column values to Text values.

Then, I tried attempting to solve this problem in 2 ways:

1. I tried converting the excel to a json file using an online converter but it didn't work well since I have text in foreign language in the excel.
2. I tried converting the excel to a csv, and then to a json file (also using an online converter to convert csv to json) and it worked but for some reason the numbers (which were stored as text) have become numbers again.

If there is a solution that involves code I'm great with that too.

Thanks

Comment: I know it's been a while, but did you figure out a solution?

Comment: Hi there,
Yes, after a while I found out about this function called "TEXT" which when combined allows you to convert numbers to strings.
For each of the columns you'd like to save it's value you should use =TEXT(CELL, "0"), then cut the values you receive and paste it as Values rather than Formula Values.